# Is start date requires date only or date containing variable is also enough?

Tags: date, unix, format

This question is related to oracle BRM event_t table partitions;

`partition_utils.pl -o add -t realtime -s u_date -q 10 -u day -f`

Here I am passing date in the form of a variable (u_date) but it is giving me an error `10025 start date is not in MMDDYYYY format`,but the u_date contains date in MMDDYYYY format only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to pass in a variable from a shell such as bash? If that's the case you have to specify $u_date instead of u_date